# Red border for three columns of a table

Tags: tables

I try to put a red border on the columns number 1,2 and 6 (upper, lower, left, right border of every cell) of the following table but starting only from the 3rd row (included!).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
\begin{table}[H]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|cc|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Principal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Period\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Radial\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Azimuthal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Magnetic quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Spin}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Maximum\\ number of\\ electrons in\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n=n_r+n_\theta$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_r=n-1,\ldots,0$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_\varphi=k=1,\ldots,n$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$l=k-1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & $m_l$ & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$m_s$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}shell} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}period} \\ \hline
    1 & K & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & 1s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} & $2$ \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & 2s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{2} & \multirow{-2}{*}{L} & $0$ & $2$ & $1$ & 2p & $-1,0+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} & \multirow{-2}{*}{$8$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $2$ & $1$ & $0$ & 3s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $2$ & $0$ & 3p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-3}{*}{3} & \multirow{-3}{*}{M} & $0$ & $3$ & $1$ & 3d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} & \multirow{-3}{*}{$18$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $3$ & $1$ & $0$ & 4s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $2$ & $1$ & 4p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $3$ & $2$ & 4d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-4}{*}{4} & \multirow{-4}{*}{N} & $0$ & $4$ & $3$ & 4f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} & \multirow{-4}{*}{$32$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $4$ & $1$ & $0$ & 5s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $3$ & $2$ & $1$ & 5p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $3$ & $2$ & 5d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $4$ & $3$ & 5f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-5}{*}{5} & \multirow{-5}{*}{O} & $0$ & $5$ & $4$ & 5g & $-4,-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3,+4$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$18$} & \multirow{-5}{*}{$50$} \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

However i fail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it bother you that `\resizebox` shrinks the table so much as to make it virtually unreadable without a magnifying glass? More importantly, how much time do you think the readers of your document will be willing to spend deciphering such a table?

Comment: Try `@{\textcolor{red}{\vline}}`

Comment: It doesn't quite fit rotated 90^\circ either.  Close, but no cigar.

Comment: Sadly i didn't found a better way than resizebox because i'm not a document designer so i lack ideas for a better design. Buţ if you have a better idea and can provide the corresponding LaTeX code you are welcome!

Comment: Where do i have to put '@{\textcolor{red}{\vline}}' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my best version.  Not sure how to do the other borders.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
\begin{table}[p]
    \centering\
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}%
    \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{|c@{\textcolor{red}{\vline}}c@{\textcolor{red}{\vline}}c|c|c|c@{\textcolor{red}{\vline}}c|c|cc|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Principal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Period\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Radial\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Azimuthal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Magnetic quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Spin}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Maximum\\ number of\\ electrons in\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n=n_r+n_\theta$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_r$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_\varphi$} & {\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$l=k-1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & $m_l$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$m_s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}shell} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}sum} \\ \hline
    1 & K & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & 1s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} & $2$ \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & 2s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{2} & \multirow{-2}{*}{L} & $0$ & $2$ & $1$ & 2p & $-1,0+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} & \multirow{-2}{*}{$8$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $2$ & $1$ & $0$ & 3s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $2$ & $0$ & 3p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-3}{*}{3} & \multirow{-3}{*}{M} & $0$ & $3$ & $1$ & 3d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} & \multirow{-3}{*}{$18$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $3$ & $1$ & $0$ & 4s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $2$ & $1$ & 4p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $3$ & $2$ & 4d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-4}{*}{4} & \multirow{-4}{*}{N} & $0$ & $4$ & $3$ & 4f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} & \multirow{-4}{*}{$32$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $4$ & $1$ & $0$ & 5s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $3$ & $2$ & $1$ & 5p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $3$ & $2$ & 5d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $4$ & $3$ & 5f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-5}{*}{5} & \multirow{-5}{*}{O} & $0$ & $5$ & $4$ & 5g & $-4,-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3,+4$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$18$} & \multirow{-5}{*}{$50$} \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very nice but.... that breaks the title row of some columns (columns #1, #2 and #7) we can't see the entire title anymore...

Comment: +1 for rendering the table in landscape mode.

Comment: There is lots of room for more title rows if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

I think a serious problem with your table is that it is well-nigh illegibile without a magnifying glass.

Please do your readers a big favor and either render the table in landscape format or apply abbreviations -- e.g., `q.n.` for `quantum number` -- and selected additional line breaks to make the columns less wide. Do also consider increasing the table's legibility by omitting all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, along the lines of the LaTeX code and associated screenshot shown below.

Observe that the table now fits within the textblock *without* having to resort to the `\resizebox` sledgehammer. Oh, and by making the entire table more legible, you can probably also skip highlighting some of the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% new:
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

%% before:
\begin{table}[H]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|cc|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Principal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Period\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Radial\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Azimuthal\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Orbital\\ notation\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Magnetic quantum\\ number\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Spin}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Maximum\\ number of\\ electrons in\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n=n_r+n_\theta$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_r=n-1,\ldots,0$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$n_\varphi=k=1,\ldots,n$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$l=k-1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}symbol} & $m_l$ & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$m_s$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}shell} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}period} \\ \hline
    1 & K & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & 1s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} & $2$ \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & 2s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{2} & \multirow{-2}{*}{L} & $0$ & $2$ & $1$ & 2p & $-1,0+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} & \multirow{-2}{*}{$8$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $2$ & $1$ & $0$ & 3s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $2$ & $0$ & 3p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-3}{*}{3} & \multirow{-3}{*}{M} & $0$ & $3$ & $1$ & 3d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} & \multirow{-3}{*}{$18$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $3$ & $1$ & $0$ & 4s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $2$ & $1$ & 4p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $3$ & $2$ & 4d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-4}{*}{4} & \multirow{-4}{*}{N} & $0$ & $4$ & $3$ & 4f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} & \multirow{-4}{*}{$32$} \\ \hline \hline
     &  & $4$ & $1$ & $0$ & 5s & $0$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$2$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $3$ & $2$ & $1$ & 5p & $-1,0,+1$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$6$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $2$ & $3$ & $2$ & 5d & $-2,-1,0,+1,+2$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$10$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
     &  & $1$ & $4$ & $3$ & 5f & $-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$14$} &  \\ \cline{3-9}
    \multirow{-5}{*}{5} & \multirow{-5}{*}{O} & $0$ & $5$ & $4$ & 5g & $-4,-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3,+4$ & $+,-$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$18$} & \multirow{-5}{*}{$50$} \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
    

%% after:
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\thickmuskip{0mu} % no space around relational operators
\setlength\medmuskip{0mu} % no space around binary operators
\scriptsize               % for a 30% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. whitespace amount

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{c} }
\toprule 
\mytab{Principal\\ q.n.} & \mytab{Period\\ notation} & 
\mytab{Radial\\ q.n.}    & \mytab{Azimuthal\\ q.n.} & 
\mytab{Orbital\\ q.n.}   & \mytab{Orbital\\ notation} & 
\mytab{Magnetic\\q.n.}   & Spin & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mytab{Max.\ \# of\\ electrons in}} \\ 
\addlinespace
$n=n_r+n_\theta$ & symbol & 
\mytab{$n_r=n-1,$\\$\ldots,0$} & 
\mytab{$n_\varphi=k=$\\$1,\ldots,n$} & 
$l=k-1$ & symbol & $m_l$ & $m_s$ & shell & period \\ 
\midrule
$1$ & K & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & 1s & $0$ & $+,-$ & $2$ & $2$ \\ 
\addlinespace % insert vertical whitespace
$2$ & L & $1$ & $1$ & $0$ & 2s & $0$ & $+,-$ & $2$ & $8$ \\ 
    &   & $0$ & $2$ & $1$ & 2p & $0,\pm1$ & $+,-$ & $6$ &  \\ 
\addlinespace
$3$ & M & $2$ & $1$ & $0$ & 3s & $0$ & $+,-$ & $2$ & $18$ \\ 
    &   & $1$ & $2$ & $0$ & 3p & $0,\pm1$ & $+,-$ & $6$ &  \\ 
    & & $0$ & $3$ & $1$ & 3d & $0,\pm1,\pm2$ & $+,-$ & $10$ & \\ 
\addlinespace
$4$ & N & $3$ & $1$ & $0$ & 4s & $0$ & $+,-$ & $2$ & $32$ \\ 
    &   & $2$ & $2$ & $1$ & 4p & $0,\pm1$ & $+,-$ & $6$ &  \\ 
    &   & $1$ & $3$ & $2$ & 4d & $0,\pm1,\pm2$ & $+,-$ & $10$ &  \\ 
    &   & $0$ & $4$ & $3$ & 4f & $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$ & $+,-$ & $14$ & \\ 
\addlinespace
$5$ & O & $4$ & $1$ & $0$ & 5s & $0$ & $+,-$ & $2$ & $50$ \\ 
    &   & $3$ & $2$ & $1$ & 5p & $0,\pm1$ & $+,-$ & $6$ &  \\ 
    &   & $2$ & $3$ & $2$ & 5d & $0,\pm1,\pm2$ & $+,-$ & $10$ &  \\ 
    &   & $1$ & $4$ & $3$ & 5f & $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$ & $+,-$ & $14$ &  \\ 
    &   & $0$ & $5$ & $4$ & 5g & $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4$ & $+,-$ & $18$ & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for optimization